# Finding point on ellipse given an arc length

Tags: integration, conic-sections

Given a parametric representation of an ellipse:

$$
x = a\cos t \\ 
y = b\sin t
$$

Say I have a known point $P_0$ at $t = t_0$. Given also a known arc length $d$ on the ellipse:

$$
d = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \sqrt{a^2\sin^2 t + b^2\cos^2t}  \ dt 
$$

Is there a way to calculate what is $t_1$ analytically?

Comment: "More generally, the arc length of a portion of the circumference, as a function of the angle subtended, is given by an incomplete [elliptic integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral)" [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse) , so I guess "no" in an arbitrary case.